# How to keep a job alive for a long time

Tags: laravel

There is a job that takes a csv and saves all the data in my database.

However, it's taking a long time and I'm having trouble keeping the job alive.

I tried passing

```
    public $tries = 1;
    public $timeout = 0;
```

its kill a job and set + 1 tries, Illuminate\Queue\Worker->maxAttemptsExceededException(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\RedisJob))

and more than 1 hour, job stays alive until 3600s and the job dies with timeout and execution time of 1704480425.45s

```
    public $tries = 1;
    public $timeout = 3600;
```

I really don't know what to do anymore

Comment: Is it normal, for your job, to take more than an hour ? It seams extremely long for an async process. How are your calling your worker? Also, the execution time, you are mentionning, looks a lot more like a unix timestamp than the number of seconds it took to run your job.

Comment: It also depends on the job worker, it is not only the job itself, but it is taking a lot of time, you should approach it differently, can't you trigger multiple jobs but each of them take care of different rows?

Comment: Also, if you plan in keeping your current timeout, you should validate the `retry_after` option, on your queue. [According to the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#worker-timeouts), if the `retry_after` option is less than the timeout, the job will timeout and restart.

Comment: @Nicolas, I mentioned the Runtime that Horizonte shows me, the job takes a huge csv and saves it in the database, validating some last update dates, This shouldn't be but it's normal

Comment: Alright than, knowing that, I'd validate the `retry_after` param, in the queue configuration, and make sure to use a queue worker that does not have a timeout in itself. It would still be a good idea to attempt to optimise your job. Having 1+ hour jobs running constantly on your server cannot be good for the overall performance of your app. Good luck !

Comment: Will try make multiples jobs like @matiaslauriti say

Comment: Divide and conquer could be a good solution to your problem. 
For example: 
1. Run 1 job to upload CSV. read csv by chunk set job 2 job next option
2. job 2 will read your data and call each data to insert - it will run for each chunk.

so, ultimately job 1 will create multiple jobs 2. and any of them won't be timed out. 

@Vowkaz